# How to interpolate missing values in my chart?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, dimple.js

I used this code (JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0zvq3gr7/):

```
        var data = [
                    { Date: "2015-09-14", DayOfMonth: 14, Type: "Views", Amount: 5, y1: 10, },
                    { Date: "2015-09-14", DayOfMonth: 14, Type: "Likes", Amount: 2, y1: 15, },
                    { Date: "2015-09-15", DayOfMonth: 15, Type: "Views", Amount: 10, y1: 35, },
                  //  { Date: "2015-09-15", DayOfMonth: 15, Type: "Likes", Amount: 4, y1: 20, },

                    { Date: "2015-09-16", DayOfMonth: 16, Type: "Views", Amount: 14, y1: 22, },
                    { Date: "2015-09-16", DayOfMonth: 16, Type: "Likes", Amount: 10, y1: 22, },
                    { Date: "2015-09-17", DayOfMonth: 27, Type: "Views", Amount: 20, y1: 22, },
                    { Date: "2015-09-17", DayOfMonth: 27, Type: "Likes", Amount: 12, y1: 22, },
                ];

var svgWidth = $("#chart").width(),
    svgHeight = $("#chart").height();

var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chart", svgWidth, svgHeight);
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
var xAxis = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "DayOfMonth");
xAxis.title = null;
xAxis.addOrderRule("Date");
var yAxis = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Amount");
yAxis.title = null;

var series = chart.addSeries("Type", dimple.plot.area);
series.stacked = false;
//series.interpolation = "cardinal";


var legend = chart.addLegend(0, 20, 300, 20, "right");

chart.draw();
```

The result is this:

[image]

In the previous example I removed:

```
{ Date: "2015-09-15", DayOfMonth: 15, Type: "Likes", Amount: 4, y1: 20, }
```

from the data. Since for the "Likes" Type DayOfMonth 15 is missing there should be a straight line between DayOfMonth 14 and 16 for "Likes". I draw this in the following graphic:

[image]

**How do I fix the wrong interpolation here?**

Comment: `why have you deleted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892402 and asked what appears to be the same question again?

Answer (score 0):

You have two objects for DayOfMonth 15 . If you remove them both it will draw a linear line between 14 and 16. Look at this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agna_desai/g7bmLtw2/1/).

```
    var data = [
                { Date: "2015-09-14", DayOfMonth: 14, Type: "Views", Amount: 5, y1: 10, },
                { Date: "2015-09-14", DayOfMonth: 14, Type: "Likes", Amount: 2, y1: 15, },
               // { Date: "2015-09-15", DayOfMonth: 15, Type: "Views", Amount: 10, y1: 35, },
              //  { Date: "2015-09-15", DayOfMonth: 15, Type: "Likes", Amount: 4, y1: 20, },
                { Date: "2015-09-16", DayOfMonth: 16, Type: "Views", Amount: 14, y1: 22, },
                { Date: "2015-09-16", DayOfMonth: 16, Type: "Likes", Amount: 10, y1: 22, },
                { Date: "2015-09-17", DayOfMonth: 27, Type: "Views", Amount: 20, y1: 22, },
                { Date: "2015-09-17", DayOfMonth: 27, Type: "Likes", Amount: 12, y1: 22, },
            ];
```

Comment: Don't you think that I would come to this solution? Of course it will draw the line correctly. The problem is that the data sometimes does not have Likes and Views at the same date.

Comment: Sometimes we miss the obvious solution so I posted that. I think the graph is plotting correctly is  it doesn't have likes for a particular month because there is no data point (to plot it against) for that month for that type.